# using AsyncTask for implementing Logout functionality for Facebook using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, android-asynctask, facebook-android-sdk

I want to create an application which uses Facebook SDK to log on to the facebook.
I was successful to implement login functionality using the same. (I would also like to mention i am using deprecated functions, i will switch over to further things later, i would like to first fix the problems that i am encountering here).
But I got problems in implementing Logout functionality. I made my research and found out that I need to implement network functionality in AsyncTasks for better performance. So,  should I implement this functionality using AsyncTask? following is my code.
Please suggest any corrections required and also further readings and articles to clear my basic concepts. I am new to Android and facing problems in understanding AsyncTasks.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.fb_button:

        try{
        if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {
 new myAsyncClass().doInBackground(fb);
            //button close session
        }

        else
        {
            fb.authorize(LoginPage.this, new DialogListener(){

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "on Facebook error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "on error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values)
                {
                    update_fb_buttonimage();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onComplete works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel()
                {

                }
            });
            //login in to facebook
        }

        }catch(Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

my asynctask class is as follows....

```
    private class myAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Facebook, Void, Void>{

     protected void onPreExecute() {
           // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
           super.onPreExecute();



          }

    @Override

    protected Void doInBackground(Facebook... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Facebook fb=arg0[0];
        try {
            fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
            update_fb_buttonimage();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
    }
```

So in my switch case if session is invalid and i click on my button i get logged on to facebook without any problem
and also my view (button) also gets updated.
but when session is valid, i get the famous exception

```
android.os.networkonmainthreadexception
```

where should I place my

```
new myAsyncClass().doInBackground(fb);
```

please suggest me!! I am totally stuck up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not call the `doInBackground()`directly while calling an AsyncTask.

You simply **`execute()`** the AsyncTask and it follows a certain sequence of execution as onPreExecute(), doInBackground(), onProgressUpdate() and onPostExecute().

So, instead of calling doInBackground(), you should be calling execute().

```
if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {
          new myAsyncClass().execute(fb);

        }
```

Comment: i did what u told. but now my app is crashing

Comment: Could you please post the LogCat ?

Comment: And yes, feel free to contact me on Facebook. :)

Comment: But still, I feel that it's better if you attached your LogCat output. It would be helpful for other users who might be having the same problem and it would also help you learn how to debug efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

OnClick on button which logout but this

```
new myAsyncClass().doInBackground(fb);
```

Comment: sorry sir, I couldn't get you. Can you please elaborate? It will be great. thankyou

Comment: @user2056245 where you want to logout fb is there any button ?

Comment: yes, the same button which i use to login , which is in the main UI thread

Comment: @user2056245 : you are doing everything right. Simply use `execute(fb)` instead of `doInBackground(fb)`. Refer to my answer for more details.